# How to redirect to Android app/play store from an Android notification of a Facebook Request?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-requests

I have an android app, from where a user can invite facebook friends to join. I have that part working fine. I used Requests API and did everything as facebook says it should be done.

However, the problem is that when the other user receives the Facebook notification, it triggers an Android Notification (at the top bar), but when this android notification is clicked NOTHING happens. If the user goes to the facebook app, and taps the notification, it sends him to the play store or app. I need the android notification to do the same.
What am I missing?

Comment: What version of the Facebook app do you have? If you're running the latest version, please file a bug with complete repro steps at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: How to invite people are explained at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#invite_to_app

Comment: @MingLi , yes it is the last version available in the Play Store, but I can't tell if this is a BUG or a bad configuration in my facebook apps dashboard.

Comment: @WizKid , I did that using the Request Dialog, and that part works fine.

Comment: And you have a canvas version of your app and your app is a game just like the documentation I linked to say?

Comment: @WizKid no, my app is a game, but it doesn't have a canvas version. The link you sent me says " If your app does not have a presence on Facebook Canvas: You may use the Message Dialog on iOS and Android" , but that's not what I need. I don't understand why the request works perfectly fine from the facebook app, but it won't work at all from the Android push notification.

Comment: The documentation clearly say that you can't use the request dialog.

Comment: That's not very clear to me, since I followed this documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/requests/v2.2?locale=es_LA , and it doesn't say something like "do not invite friends using Request Dialog if you app does not have a canvas version" .. it actually says " Requests are sent via the Requests Dialog, which is invoked in-game via the Facebook SDK on iOS, Android and Canvas.  " . I fail to see where the problem is here, because from the facebook app I can click the notification and open my Android app.

Answer (score 0):

To get redirected form clicking on notification you should use

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,*YourClass.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent ,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

Explained here: [TheNewBoston](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NgQzJ0s0XmM&index=62&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBsvRxJJOzG4r4k_zLKrnxl)

Comment: I need to open my app from a facebook push notification (that comes from a user sending a facebook request to another user), I don't get where you say I should put that code.

Comment: "android notification is clicked NOTHING happens"
This got me confused...sorry 
This is for your own application notification not for fb 
sorry